# What the type is auto & x = const int *?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, type-deduction

In a `main` function, I created a variable of `const int` pointer, assign it to a variable declared by `auto&`. Then using the `decltype(x)` to check the type. I expected the type is `const int*`. But `is_same` returns `false`.

```
int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    const int * cp_val= &a;
    auto& x = cp_val;
    bool is_const_int_ptr = std::is_same<decltype(x), const int *>::value; // returns 0

    // *x = 100; // error: assignment of read-only location '* x'
}
```

But if I add the following helper function:

```
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>

template<typename T> 
void print_type(T)
{cout << "type T is: "<< boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<T>().pretty_name()<< '\n';}
```

In the main, I invoke the function

```
print_type(x); // It returns int const*
```

Am I missing something in `std::is_same`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Template argument deduction and `auto` are intimately related: The declaration `auto x = e;` gives `x` the same type as `f(e)` would give to `T` in an invented function `template <typename T> f(T);`, and similarly for `auto&` and `f(T&)`, `const auto*` and `f(const T*)`, etc.

Therefore, to get the correct answer from Boost, you need to declare:

```
template <typename T> void print_type(T&);
//                                   ^^^^
```

The type of `x` is of course `const int*&`.

Answer (score 6):

Note that for `auto& x`, you're declaring `x` as reference explicitly; then its type should be `const int *&`, i.e. a reference to pointer to `const int`.

Here's a better idea (from *Effective Modern C++* (Scott Meyers)) to get the accurate type at compile time from the compiling error message.

```
template <typename>
struct TD;
```

then use it as

```
TD<decltype(x)> td;
```

you'll get error message like

```
source_file.cpp:15:21: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'TD<const int *&>'
    TD<decltype(x)> td;
                    ^
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/MLZL39016)

Your helper function takes parameter by value; the reference-ness of the argument will be ignored in type deduction, that's why you got `const int*`.